Is it possible to control ios screen (Real device not simulator) programatically?
I am trying to build an application that interacts with iphone screen to perform operations like touch/tap/swipe (Not inside an app but whole screen). The closest tool to do it is FB IDB (Ios Development Bridge). But IDB doesn't support UI interactions with physical device, quoting that apple doesn't allow it. Is it possible to do it? If not, is there any official document that quotes apple doesn't allow UI interactions on physical devices, programmatically ?

Yes, asYou can use webagentdriver to control physical ios phone by installing it on the phone and get the right certificate for it.
Documentation is here https://appium.github.io/appium-xcuitest-driver/4.25/wda-custom-server/
phone configurations can be found here
https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/preparation/index.md

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
